# Resizing Application Windows in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac

Ok. Here is my Question.

Lets open a Finder window/screen.

- Stretch the Finder screen from bottom-right corner.
- When we stretch the screen, we can see that Finder screen can be sizable even behind the dock screen.
- Lets start other application like TextEdit.
- Stretch TextEdit in the same way.
- Some times, we might stretch the text editor even behind the dock window.
- Some times not?

Why it is so?

Let me give the example how I do the same thing.

- Click on spotlight search.
- Write text editor
- Open application
- Stretch it as max as possible
- Here you can see that stretching isn't possible behind dock.
- Now, move the text editor in such a way so that the bottom corner of text editor can go behind dock.
- Now stretch again.
- Now stretching is possible even behind dock.

Why it is so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is part of the design of the Dock: It's designed to not allow windows to behind the dock to eliminate the confusion of trying to access something in the window that has now fallen behind the dock.

However in order to not break resizing when the window bottom right is below the Dock's height position it will still allow you to resize the window and put it behind the Dock.

Annoying yes but part of the design.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, that's really annoying.  That's why I use "Automatically hide and show the Dock" in System Preferences.

Comment: but some times auto hiding of dock - disturbs you while working. It automatically pop up when not required.

Comment: @sagar: It's never done that to me.  However, I do see the tops of icons for a moment when they bounce, since the dock is really just translated downward.  Oh, you mean when you move the mouse to the bottom of the screen, don'tcha.

Comment: That's true, but in my opinion that's much better than having a chunk of screen dedicated to it at all times.

Answer (score 1):

Ahhh yes. The magical 'problems' of window resizing in OS X!

If the bottom of the application is 'below' or 'underneath' the Dock, then it will allow you to resize it even further underneath it. Otherwise, it will not let you resize it underneath the Dock.

I suppose they do this to limit confusion (should the click go to the Dock, or the application?), improve visibility, and to aid in Window management (so you can make all your windows the exact same height.